# Location Data of apple's Core Location

Tags: iphone, core-location

I want to know about Core Location data which is generated by apple.My question is that up to which % is it correct.Whatever I have seen it is not GPS data.Most of time it is collected data from Wifi or cell tower.So data is not 100 % accurate.

If it is anything else then give me some idea as i make it 100 % accurate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The framework will prefer the fastest, least battery-draining method to get you a location. But if you have a specific accuracy that you need, you just have to tell your CLLocationManager. Look for the desiredAccuracy property and set that.

Also, when you get locations back you should check the CLLocation's accuracy properties to see if that particular observation was accurate enough to do whatever it is you want to do.

Keep in mind that sometimes your users may in a place with good tower or WiFi but poor GPS visibility. So then you'll have to decide if the accuracy you get back is good enough or if you need to tell the user that the function is not possible.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I understand whatever you are asking but problem is the followings.Let one user is traveling by car an at the time of starting he start the application to calculate traveled distance.But after traveling 10 km distance it is showing 8 km.Fact is that in application if gps data is not available it discard some coordinate information.So what will be best approach to give some accuracy of data using core location. thanks for any kind of help.

Comment: Well, then you ask for AccuracyBest or AccuracyBestForNavigation. But you have to be prepared for the possibility that the phone may not physically be able to get a GPS fix at all times.

Answer (score 4):

It's not possible for it to be 100% accurate - the return from the API says so, even going so far as giving you the margin for error in every dataset you receive

Comment: I want to calculate distance when users is travelling by car using iphone.But as it's data is error prone so after travelling 10 km it gives not 10 km. It gives different distance some time 8 km or 12 or another error data set.So what can I do?Any suggestion